# Is there anyway to extract the list of steps from a Cucumber feature file?

Tags: cucumber

Is there any way to extract list of steps used in a Cucumber .feature file? The steps should be in the format they're defined in the step definition @When / @Given / @Then annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Use runner class to generate steps with annotations then later fill with java code topass your unit test cases ,Follow this reference link step by step procedure http://www.automationtestinghub.com/cucumber-step-definition/

Answer (score 0):

We can generate the list of steps by either using the runner class or using the tidy gherkin plugin which is available as extension in chrome
[image]